# Почему получается ошибка компиляции при объявлении массива?

Tags: java

Сама задача выглядит так:

> - Создать класс "Сотрудник" с полями: ФИО, должность, email, телефон, зарплата, возраст;
> - Конструктор класса должен заполнять эти поля при создании объекта;
> - Внутри класса «Сотрудник» написать метод, который выводит информацию об объекте в консоль;
> - Создать массив из 5 сотрудников Пример: Person[] persArray = new Person[5]; // Вначале объявляем массив объектов persArray[0] = new Person("Ivanov Ivan", "Engineer", "ivivan@mailbox.com", "892312312", 30000, 30); // потом для каждой ячейки массива задаем объект persArray[1] = new Person(...); ... persArray[4] = new Person(...);
> - С помощью цикла вывести информацию только о сотрудниках старше 40 лет;

Вот что у меня получилось:

```
public class Employee {

    //если я правильно поняла, переменные и есть поля?

    String name; //ФИО
    String position; //должность
    String email; //емейл
    String phone_number; //номер телефона

    int salary; //зарплата
    int age; //возраст
    int i = 0; //для цикла

    //это считается заполнением полей при создании?

    Employee(String name, String position, String emeil, String phone_number, int salary, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.position = position;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone_number = phone_number;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.age = age;
    }

//метод для вывода на экран информации об объекте. Ругается (( не знаю, как оформить надо
    private static void output_on_display (persArray[i]) {
        System.out.printf("Имя: %s \tДолжность: %s \nEmail: %s \t Номер телефона: %s \n Зарплата: %d \t Возраст: %d \n",
            name, position, email, phone_number, salary, age);
    }

    //Ругается на всё подряд! Не понимаю ничего
    Employee[] persArray = new Employee[5];
    persArray[0] = new Employee("Вячеслав Кобрин", "Генеральный директор", "vk@primer,ru". "+79996665544", 250000, 55);
    persArray[1] = new Employee("Иван Зайцев", "Директор по развитию", "vz@primer,ru". "+79998884455", 127000, 42);
    persArray[2] = new Employee("Дмитрий Медведев", "Охранник", "dm@primer,ru". "+79997771234", 19000, 21);
    persArray[3] = new Employee("Олеся Лисина", "Ведущий разработчик", "ol@primer,ru". "+79995554789", 120000, 28);
    persArray[4] = new Employee("Кристина Волкова", "Директор по работе с клиентами", "kv@primer,ru". "+79994445896", 138000, 48);

    //цикл

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if {//вот тут надо указать, что конкретный параметр удовлетворяет условию, но я не знаю как это сделать
             output_on_display();
        }
    }
}
```

Очень прошу тыкнуть в названия тем, которые надо почитать, чтобы оформить корректно всё. Я даже не понимаю, что конкретно гуглить.

*Конкретные вопросы:*

В методе `output_on_display()` неправильно указан аргумент? Компилятор ругается.
В массиве ругается вообще на весь этот блок, что не так?
Как в цикле сделать проверку именно по одному параметру объекта?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, **в чём именно вы видите проблему**, как её воспроизвести, **что вы хотите получить в результате** и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: заполнение массива и его вывод надо писать в методе (В методе `main` для запуска вашей программы) или в любом другом удобном вами методе. Разве вам не сказали что код пишется в методах класса? окромя его полей.

Comment: @Tsyklop вот сейчас стыдненько было.. Это решило несколько сразу вопросов. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - переопределите базовый метод toString() отвечающий за текстовое представление объекта.
2 - создайте нужный метод печати, например print(), который просто будет выводить в консоль то что мы получили в п.1. this - указатель на сам объект, метод которого вызывается
3 - исправьте ошибки в создании массива (тут "vk@primer,ru".  какая то странная запятая). 
4 - реализуйте перебор массива и вывод на печать текстового представления объект по нужному вам условию.
Названия переменных и реализация текстового представления оставлены оригинальные.

```
public class Employee {
    // это поля класса
    String name; //ФИО
    String position; //должность
    String email; //емейл
    String phone_number; //номер телефона
    int salary; //зарплата
    int age; //возраст

    // это конструктор
    public Employee(String name, String position, String email, String phone_number, int salary, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.position = position;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone_number = phone_number;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.age = age;
        }

    // это переопределенный метод
    @Override
    public String toString(){
            return String.format("Имя: %s \tДолжность: %s \nEmail: %s \t Номер телефона: %s \n Зарплата: %d \t Возраст: %d \n",
                    name, position, email, phone_number, salary, age);}

    // это метод вывода в консоль (как по заданию)
    public void print(){
        System.out.println(this);
        }


    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        Employee[] persArray = new Employee[5];
                persArray[0] = new Employee("Вячеслав Кобрин", "Генеральный директор", "vk@primer,ru", "+79996665544", 250000, 55);
                persArray[1] = new Employee("Иван Зайцев", "Директор по развитию", "vz@primer,ru", "+79998884455", 127000, 42);
                persArray[2] = new Employee("Дмитрий Медведев", "Охранник", "dm@primer,ru", "+79997771234", 19000, 21);
                persArray[3] = new Employee("Олеся Лисина", "Ведущий разработчик", "ol@primer,ru", "+79995554789", 120000, 28);
                persArray[4] = new Employee("Кристина Волкова", "Директор по работе с клиентами", "kv@primer,ru", "+79994445896", 138000, 48);

        // если у объекта в ячейке i поле age > 40, то у него вызывается метод print()
        for (int i=0; i < persArray.length; i++)
        if (persArray[i].age > 40) persArray[i].print();

    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Некоторые вещи, которые здесь есть, нам не объясняли, но теперь хоть буду видеть, что искать и читать. Особое спасибо за комментарии

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогло, а то никак последнюю строчку с возрастом не мог написать.